# Magento 2: Show total items count in Knockout template

Tags: magento2, knockoutjs, mini-cart, totals

I want to display the total items count using Knockout, in `Magento_Checkout::header/minicart.phtml`, e.g. if I have 2 items with the same SKU in the basket then the total items count is 1.

I have tried using `data-bind="text: getCartParam('items_count')"` but this returns the total quantity (i.e. 2).

I could use `<?php echo $this->helper('\Magento\Checkout\Helper\Cart')->getItemsCount(); ?>` but I'd like to try and use a Knockout binding instead - is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to Admin -> Stores -> Configuration -> Sales -> Checkout -> MyCart -> Display Cart Summary

There you can change the setting.[image]

Comment: What version of Magento 2 are you using? On 2.1.6 there is no `Checkout` option under `Sales`.

Comment: I've attached a screenshot. I'm using 2.1.5 but it is there in 2.1.6 too on my local testing machine.

Comment: Ohh is that under `stores > config`? You didn't mention that in your answer so I was going to `admin > sales` not `admin > stores > config > sales`.

Comment: Ah I see. Of course that would be found under configuration. Sorry I'll edit the answer to make it more clear.

Comment: Thanks, unchecking "Use system value" and changing to "Display number of items in cart" worked for me - although I had to edit the basket to get the minicart to show the new totals while developing locally.

Answer (score 0):

you can use like this in template file

```
<span class="number"><!-- ko text: cartSidebar().items.length --><!-- /ko --></span>
```